# Powershell Script to stop/start IIS in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, service

Essentially what the subject says. I have tried:

```
 stop-service -name iisadmin,was,w3svc -passThru
```

However 'iisadmin' is not found. What gives?

Comment: What does `gsv *iis*` return?

Comment: It returns nothing at all. But IIS websites run just fine in my Windows10 machine.

Comment: IISAdmin does not install by default with the web server role. Can you run `get-windowsfeature -Name Web-Mgmt-Compat | select InstallState` and verify that you have installed IIS 6 Management Capability feature? The result should be **Installed**.

Comment: Are you able to locate the IIS service in the services.msc console? If so, take the name from there?

Comment: Why cannot you call `iisreset /stop`?

Comment: @IvanMirchev The iis service doesn't appear in services.msc which is indeed very weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS admin service is mainly used to handle Metabase.

So please ensure Internet information service->Management tools->**IIS 6 management compatibility**->**IIS 6 Metabase compatibility** has been installed.

When you finish installing this feature, IIS Admin service will be displayed in Service.msc. And your Powershell command would start working.
[image]